# $l:V \to F$ Prove: $\exists B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}, \forall v \in V$: If $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i \Rightarrow l(v) = a_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

$l:V \to F$ Prove: $\exists B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}, \forall v \in V:$ for B base: If $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i$

Let $l \neq0$   be a linear form of $V,\: \dim V = n, n \in \Bbb N$.

We need to prove that: 
$$
\exists B = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}
$$

Where $B$ is a base of $V$, such that:

$$
\forall v \in V:
$$

If

$$
v = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_iv_i
$$

So:

$$
l(v) = a_1
$$

---

### What I tried:

By the definition of linear form, if i get that:

$$
l(v_1) = 1
$$

And:

$$
l(v_i) = 0 \ (  1 <  \forall i \leq n)
$$

I thought maybe an orthonormal base, but it doesnt seem to help me somehow...

I know its not a lot but I am just stuck here and don't have an idea.

I would like a hint (more than a solution, because those are my homeworks)

Thanks.

Comment: You are right that an orthonormal basis can help with satisfying $l(v_1) = 1$ and $l(v_i)=0$ for $i \ge 2$, which would complete the proof. To find $v_1$, it may help to realize that linear forms can be written as $l(v) = w^\top v$ for some vector $w$.

Comment: Thank you very much, if i wont be able to solve until tomorrow ill give up and ask for help, until then, thank you alot @angryavian

Comment: -_- Still stuck @angryavian

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be some orthonormal basis for $V$.
For any scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ if $v = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e_i$ then $l(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i l(e_i)$.

Let $\tilde{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n l(e_i) e_i$, and let $v_1 = \tilde{v} / \|\tilde{v}\|$ be its normalization. This can be extended to a full orthonormal basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ for $V$ (e.g., by Gram-Schmidt). Check that $l(v_1)=1$, and that $l(v_i) =0$ for $i \ge 2$.

Comment: By quick look it seems you get to the answer, can you please just give me a hint? even as a comment? i want to think alittle more before giving up

Comment: And of course, thanks alot